# Angular returns [object Object]

Tags: angularjs

my Angular code returns [object Object]. I am calling 2 controllers on different pages. First one sets the data on ng-click and the second one gets (displays) the data. Here is the code:

**Angular App code:**

```
    var careerApp = angular.module("careerApp", []);
careerApp.factory('myService', function () {
    var savedData = {};
    function set(data) {
        savedData = data;
    }
    function get() {
        return savedData;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});
careerApp.controller("JobList", function ($scope,myService) {
    myService.set(data);
});
careerApp.controller("JobSelection", function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.jobname = myService.get();
});
```

**HTML on Page 1**

```
<div class="center-details" ng-controller="JobList">
<div class="details" ng-click="set(data)" >
<h2 class="name" ng-model="jobtitle">
Winter
</h2>
<p><b>Job ID#</b> <span class="jobid">2017-01</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

**HTML on Page 2**

```
<div ng-controller="JobSelection">
<label ng-bind="jobname"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you getting the  [object Object] ? in the console or in the html?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Angular expressions intead of ng-bind. Otherwise you will have to specify a specific property of your object.

page 1

```
<div class="center-details" ng-controller="JobList">
<div class="details" ng-click="set('Winter')" >
<h2 class="name">
Winter
</h2>
<p><b>Job ID#</b> <span class="jobid">2017-01</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
careerApp.controller("JobList", function ($scope,myService) {
    $scope.set= function(data){
       myService.set(data);
    }
});
```

page 2

```
<label ng-bind="jobname"></label>
<label>{{jobname}}</label>
```

How to make it dynamically, based on the input

```
<input stype="text" ng-model="jobTitle" ng-change="set()" >
    <h2 class="name">
    {{jobTitle}}
    </h2>
```

Controller:

```
careerApp.controller("JobList", function ($scope,myService) {
        $scope.jobTitle = "";

        //This function will be called every time that jobTitle change its value.
        $scope.set= function(){
           myService.set($scope.jobTitle);
        }
    });
```

**Notes:**

Take into account that `ng-model` directive binds an input, select, textarea value to a property on the scope.

Since you have this assignment in your controller definition

```
$scope.jobname = myService.get();
```

If you run this controller before the user make a click it will be empty. it wont be refreshed in every click.

Comment: by doing this, it gives output as "{}"

Comment: That is because data object is empty. What are you trying to save in there?

Comment: I am trying to save the jobtitle, please refer the HTML code of page 1 above, where the value is Winter. I want to store that value on ng-click and pass it on to the 2nd controller on page 2 and display at jobname binding

Comment: Yo have a few things missing then. Do you want it to be an input? or just a  static value?

Comment: Just a static value

Comment: That worked! :-) Really appreciate your help. Can you also suggest, what if I want to set the data dynamically? means, if the value of H2 changes, it should reflect in the output. instead of assigning a static value of 'Winter' to set(data), can I assign a value of a particular <div> or <span> or <h2> for example ?

Comment: Glad it worked. I edited the answer again, please check.

Answer (score 4):

You are bringing the whole object in

```
<label ng-bind="jobname"></label>
```

If you intented to write the object with a better formatting try changing it to:

```
<label> {{ jobname | json }}</label>
```

This way it will be formatted and printed as a json object.

Comment: by doing this as well, it gives output as "{}"

Comment: @user2185457 then just change `myService.set(data);` to f.e. `myService.set('text');`